# AJAX HTTP request refresh content

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Why does it always keep saying "loading...", and not showing the content of data.php?

```
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();             
function getdata () {
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState = 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        } 
        else {
            document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = "loading...";
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "data.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the status is 200?

```
if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 ) { //<-- typo 
    if(xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    } else {
            document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = xmlhttp.status + ": " + xmlhttp.statusText;
    } 
} else {
    document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = "loading...";
}
```

---

Now you said the status is zero, that means you are not cancelling the click event/form submission that called the function that makes the Ajax request. I am guessing you are using an inline event handler so it would look something like this:

```
<a href="foo.gif" onclick="getdata(); return false;">
<form onsubmit="getdata(); return false;">
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you always get "Loading"... but you missed compare operator in line:

```
if(xmlhttp.readyState = 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
```

must be

```
if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
```

Comment: <?php
 echo "ok";
?>

this is data.php

Comment: xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://[domain]/data.php", true);
try to set absolute path to data.php

Comment: thanks man it worked how to set a time request for example refresh every 20 sec?

Comment: function recall(){
  setTimeout(function(){ getdata(); recall(); }, 20000);
};
recall();